# The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

> I am trying to upload a file using multipart

**Controller**

```
// update user details
    @RequestMapping(value = "/profile/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView updateProfile(@ModelAttribute User user, HttpServletRequest request) {

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("settings");

        if (!user.getFile().getOriginalFilename().equals("")) {
            FileUploadUtility.uploadFile(request, user.getFile(), user.getUserCode());
        }

        boolean isUserUpdated = userService.isUserUpdated(user);


        if (isUserUpdated) {
            mv.addObject("message", "Succesfully Updated!");

            userModel = (UserModel) request.getSession().getAttribute("userModel");
            userModel.setName(user.getName());
            // some code here for successful registration//
            System.out.println("Succssful");
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:/home");
        } else {
            mv.addObject("message", "Updation Failed!");
            System.err.println("Unsuccssful");
            // some code here for unsuccessful registration//

            return mv;
        }

    }
```

**Jsp page**

```
<sf:form class="form" action="${contextRoot}/profile/update"
                modelAttribute="userProfile" method="POST"
                enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validate();">
                <!-- BEGIN BASIC ELEMENTS -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="card" style="text-align: center;">
                                <div class="card-body ">
                                    <h2>Avatar</h2>
                                    <img class="img-circle"
                                        src="${images}/${userProfile.userCode}.jpg"
                                        style="height: 150px; width: 150px;" />
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            <p>
                                                <span style="color: #296093; font-size: 20px;">${userProfile.name}
                                                </span> <br /> <small style="color: #3d3d3d; font-weight: bold;">${userProfile.role}</small>
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                                            <sf:input id="file" class="inputfile" type="file" path="file" />
                                            <label for="file"><span>Choose a file&hellip;</span></label>
                                            <br /> <span style="color: #d62424" id="file_error"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--end .col -->
```

> **`Whenever i click on save i receive this error:`** The server cannot or
>   will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be
>   a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request
>   message framing, or deceptive request routing).

Comment: Try point 6 of [Docs](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-file-upload)